# Open / lunch mutiple pdf file at ones with C?

Tags: c, gcc, terminal

I am trying to lean C.

I has make this lille program / daemon.

The meaning is any .pdf in your 'Taskfolder'-->(ROOTFOLDER).

Will be open / lunch on start-up via 'evince'.

Do I need to lead abort threading or is there a better way to do this?

I has try something like system("envice 1.pdf && envice 2.pdf ...");

But this still just open the pdf files one at the time.

The code look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROOTFOLDER ((const unsigned char *)"/home/myusername/Taskfolder/")
#define LUNCHERAPP ((const unsigned char *)"evince ")

int main()
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char *ext;
    d = opendir(ROOTFOLDER);
    if(d)
    {
        int i=0;
        char *tmp;
        while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            ext = strchr(dir->d_name, '.');
            if((ext != NULL) && (ext != 0) && (strcmp(strchr(ext ,'.'), ".pdf") == 0))
            {
                tmp = malloc(strlen(LUNCHERAPP) + strlen(ROOTFOLDER) + strlen(dir->d_name) + 1);
                strcat(tmp, LUNCHERAPP);
                strcat(tmp, ROOTFOLDER);
                strcat(tmp, dir->d_name);
                printf("pdf== %s\n", tmp);
                system(tmp);// <-- 'evince ~/Taskfolder/filename.pdf'
                free(tmp);
                ++i;
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE-CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define APP ((const unsigned char *)"evince")
#define ROOTFOLDER ((const unsigned char *)"./")
int main()
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char *ext;
    d = opendir(ROOTFOLDER);
    if(d)
    {
        char *cmd = malloc(1);
        strcat(cmd, APP);
        while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            ext = strchr(dir->d_name, '.');
            if((ext != NULL) && (ext != 0) && (strcmp(ext, ".pdf") == 0))
            {
                cmd = realloc(cmd, strlen(cmd)+strlen(ROOTFOLDER)+strlen(dir->d_name)+1);
                strcat(cmd, " ");
                strcat(cmd, ROOTFOLDER);
                strcat(cmd, dir->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
        printf("\nrun:\n%s\n", cmd);
        system(cmd);
        free(cmd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strchr(ext ,'.') could return 0.

Comment: thanks :) so I need to add an if(ext != 0)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with envice, but this command:

```
"envice 1.pdf && envice 2.pdf ..."
```

Will execute envice one time for each file. I don't think that's what you intended. I think you intended to execute envice one time with all the files on its command line. If that is correct, you need to leave out the `&&` and format it like this:

```
"envice 1.pdf 2.pdf ..."
```